# Getting Pandas NaT to propagate like NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I'm trying to take the min and max of a couple Pandas Series objects containing datetime64 data in the face of NaT. np.minimum and np.maximum work the way I want if the dtype is float64. That is, once any element in the comparison is NaN, NaN will be the result of that comparison. For example:

```
>>> s1
0    0.0
1    1.8
2    3.6
3    5.4
dtype: float64
>>> s2
0    10.0
1    17.0
2     NaN
3    14.0
dtype: float64
>>> np.maximum(s1, s2)
0    10.0
1    17.0
2     NaN
3    14.0
dtype: float64
>>> np.minimum(s1, s2)
0    0.0
1    1.8
2    NaN
3    5.4
dtype: float64
```

This doesn't work if s1 and s2 are datetime64 objects:

```
>>> s1
0   2199-12-31
1   2199-12-31
2   2199-12-31
3   2199-12-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> s2
0          NaT
1   2018-10-30 
2          NaT
3          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> np.maximum(s1, s2)
0   2199-12-31
1   2199-12-31
2   2199-12-31
3   2199-12-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> np.minimum(s1, s2)
0   2199-12-31
1   2018-10-30
2   2199-12-31
3   2199-12-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I expected indexes 0, 2 and 3 to turn up as NaT whether computing the min or max. (I realize numpy's functions might not have been the best choice, but I was not successful finding suitable Pandas analogs.)

After doing a bit of reading, I came to realize NaT is only approximately NaN, the latter having a proper floating point representation. Further reading suggested no simple way to have NaT "pollute" these comparisons. What's the correct way to get NaT to propagate in min/max comparisons the way NaN does in a floating point context? Maybe there are Pandas equivalents to numpy.{maximum,minimum} which are NaT-aware?

Answer (score 2):

[`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) seems one solution which doesn't give up on vectorisation:

```
s1 = pd.Series([pd.datetime(2099, 12, 31)]*4)
s2 = pd.Series([pd.NaT, pd.datetime(2018, 10, 30), pd.NaT, pd.NaT])

null_check = s1.isnull() | s2.isnull()
res_max = np.maximum(s1, s2).mask(null_check, np.nan)
res_min = np.minimum(s1, s2).mask(null_check, np.nan)

print(res_max)
print(res_min)

0          NaT
1   2099-12-31
2          NaT
3          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
0          NaT
1   2018-10-30
2          NaT
3          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

As you found, the *reason* for the behaviour you see is that `pd.NaT` has an associated `int` value and this is used for comparison operations:

```
print(pd.to_numeric(pd.Series([pd.NaT])))

0   -9223372036854775808
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's the best way, but if you change the type of s1 and s2 to `object` with `astype`, then using `np.minimum` and `np.maximum` works and you still get a series of `datetime64[ns]`, for example:

```
print (np.maximum(s1.astype(object), s2.astype(object)))
0          NaT
1   2199-12-31
2          NaT
3          NaT
Name: 1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I'm not able to get that to work (Pandas 0.23.4, NumPy 1.15.1).
```
>>> np.maximum(s1.astype(object), s2.astype(object))
0   2199-12-31
1   2199-12-31
2   2199-12-31
3   2199-12-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: @smontanaro yeah, I was thinking this might be version dependent, but I could not verify it. My versions are a bit older. Does `np.where(s1 > s2, s1,s2)` gives you what you want? I think it was working for me

Comment: Note `object` dtype gives up on vectorisation: it may work, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have this figured out. (Well, at least I figured out one way to skin the cat.) It's not terribly pretty, but it's much faster than my original solution embedding all the logic in apply(). Briefly, the solution involves translating the datetime elements to ints, mapping the int version of pd.NaT to np.nan, applying np.minimum/np.maximum, then translating back to datetime64. apply() is still involved, but the logic is much reduced from what I originally had. (No doubt it can still be improved. I'm not much of a Pandas/NumPy guy...)

```
>>> s1 = pd.Series([pd.NaT, pd.datetime(2018, 10, 30), pd.NaT, pd.NaT])
>>> s1
0          NaT
1   2018-10-30
2          NaT
3          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> nanish = int(pd.NaT)
>>> nanish
-9223372036854775808
>>> s2 = pd.to_numeric(s1)
>>> s2
0   -9223372036854775808
1    1540857600000000000
2   -9223372036854775808
3   -9223372036854775808
dtype: int64
>>> s3 = s2.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x == nanish else x)
>>> s3
0             NaN
1    1.540858e+18
2             NaN
3             NaN
dtype: float64
>>> s5 = np.maximum(s3, s4)
>>> s5
0             NaN
1    1.540858e+18
2             NaN
3             NaN
dtype: float64
>>> s6 = pd.to_datetime(s5)
>>> s6
0          NaT
1   2018-10-30
2          NaT
3          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: You should avoid `apply` + `lambda`. This is a Python-level loop which effectively gives up on vectorisation.

Comment: `s2.apply(lambda x: np.nan if x == nanish else x)` → `s2.replace(nanish, np.nan)`